# Issue with "+" character on var

Tags: javascript, jquery, string-concatenation

I have a problem with the character "+" inside a string passed to jQuery object $()

I tried to initialize String object and concat but the problem remains the same.

```
function fn(string){
    $(string).show();
}

let myString = ".my-class-that-contains+";
fn(myString);
```

The code doesn't response as expected. When i remove the character "+" from the end of the string all works fine.

Comment: `The code doesn't response as expected` -- What is the expectation and how does it differ from the response?

Comment: What is this supposed to do? Because `$("You need to know about c++")` shouldn't match anything.

Comment: `$(string).show()`; makes no sense

Answer (score 1):

`+` has a defined meaning in a selector. It is a [sibling combinator](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#sibling-combinators).

To use it in a class name in a class selector, you need to escape it (with a `\`).

Remember that the CSS escape character is also the JavaScript escape character so you have to escape the `\` characters in the selector to put them in the JavaScript string literal.

```js
function fn(string){
    $(string).show();
}

let myString = ".my-class-that-contains\\+";
fn(myString);
```

```css
div { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="my-class-that-contains+">
This is hidden by default
</div>
```

It is best to avoid using special characters in class names in the first place.

Comment: Here is an example from the jQuery documentation: https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Answer (score 0):

you can use like selector for it.

```
  function fn(string){
    // $(string).show();

    $('[class="'+string+'"]').show();
    }

    let myString = ".my-class-that-contains+";
    fn(myString);
```

**For reference:**
https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/